# Некорректное отображение Flex в Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

В IE11, когда у изображения ширина больше, чем высота, изображение вылазит за блок. Каким образом можно от этого избавиться?

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #00f;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

img{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `flex` в `img`

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #00f;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

img{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;  
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 100%; 
  -moz-flex: 1 1 100%;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 100%;
  flex: 1 1 100%;    
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></div>
```